# Обособление выражения с "как"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли выделить запятыми выделенное выражение в следующем предложении? Мне кажется, что нет, но хочу разъяснений.

> За такое короткое время ***как 40 секунд*** он успевает сделать 50 полных отжиманий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Здесь действует следующее правило: запятыми выделяются или отделяются сравнительные обороты,если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово так, такой, тот, столь.
Ср: Ямщик был в таком же изумлении от его щедрости, как и сам француз от предложения Дубровского (Пушкин);

***См.:Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ***

Comment: Спасибо, Серж!!